# Why is NaN a global variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've noticed that `NaN` is implemented as a global variable (`window.NaN`) whose value is `NaN`. 
Why is this the case? Wouldn't it make more sense for it to be a reserved word that represents a value, like `true`, `false`, and `null`?

**EDIT** apparently this is in the spec, along with `undefined` and `Infinity`. WTF JavaScript?!

Comment: How did you check how its defined?

Comment: [`undefined` is not a reserved word either.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3)

Comment: @rhino good catch, changing that in the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not just *implemented* that way, it's [specified that way](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1):

> 15.1.1 Value Properties of the Global Object
>
> 15.1.1.1 `NaN`
>
> The value of `NaN` is `NaN` (see 8.5). This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.
>
> 15.1.1.2 `Infinity`
>
> The value of `Infinity` is +∞ (see 8.5). This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.
>
> 15.1.1.3 `undefined`
>
> The value of `undefined` is `undefined` (see 8.1). This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

*(The global object is the window object on browsers.)* An implementation that doesn't do it is violating the spec. :-)

As for why: The spec doesn't seem to say why, so unless someone can find a quote from Brendan Eich explaining his reasoning... :-) I will just <s>speculate</s> mention that making them globals is somewhat less limiting: You can have a local `Infinity` variable in your code meaning something else if you don't need access to the global one. You couldn't do that if it were a reserved word. Mind you, it opens the door to trouble as well, so...

Comment: "You couldn't do that if it were a reserved word."

You *shoudn't* ever do that, even though they aren't reserved words. It's weird that you'd have a feature in a language that, as you said, "opens the door to trouble" with no compelling reason to do so.

Comment: @DanielWeiner: Oh, I wholeheartedly agree that you *shouldn't* do that (although I'd be surprised if `Infinity` weren't shadowed regularly by people who didn't know it even existed).

Comment: I'll accept your answer as the correct one, but this is one of the most WTF-y things I've seen in JavaScript. And I've seen a lot.

Comment: @DanielWeiner: I haven't found anything from Eich that explains this decision. Would be great if someone did. It could easily be "Because I had to do JavaScript in 10 days in May 1995 and this is...what happened." :-)

Comment: @DanielWeiner I agree with you: Given  `var a=NaN;` the comparison `a==a` will be always false. And `typeof NaN` is "number" (Not a Number is a number? WTF!)

Comment: @Pablo: `typeof NaN` being `"number"` makes perfect sense, because `NaN` is a value with specific meaning in IEEE-754 double-precision floating point (the kind used by JavaScript and most other modern languages). So it's a number-typed representation of that value. It's like `null` being of type object: It's something that's typed as an object reference, which refers to no object. But I've ***never*** understood why `NaN` isn't equal to itself. (They even special-cased that in the new `Map` and `Set`: If `NaN` is a key in a map, or a value in a set, it matches itself like any other num does.)

Answer (score 0):

NaN is a JavaScript global property that is defined just like (at the same level) as undefined or infinity.

See picture below:

[image: Nan and other global properties]

The fact that it is global allows the broadest possible access.  JavaScript global properties and functions can be used with all the built-in JavaScript objects.

Comment: *"The fact that it is global allows the broadest possible access."* If it were a reserved word as the OP mentioned, it would also have that broadest possible access -- **and** you couldn't shadow it.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder that's right. Then we have to guess why NaN was specified thet way it was specified